# Numerical approximation of $\pi$

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, random

> Points are randomly scattered inside the unit square, some fall within the unit circle with probability  $P=\pi/4$.
>
> so
> $P$ is approximated by the fraction $$P\approx \frac{\text{Number of red points}}{\text{Number of all points}}$$
> this leads
> $$\pi \approx 4\frac{\text{Number of red points}}{\text{Number of all points}}$$
> (see following image)

There is a code for this:

```
tinyColor[color_, point_] := {PointSize[Small], color, Point[point]} 
colorChoose[point_] := 
If[Norm[point] <= 1, tinyColor[Red, point], tinyColor[Blue, point]] 
darts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {40000, 2}]; 
coloredDarts =ParallelMap[colorChoose, darts];
insides = Map[Boole[Norm[#] <= 1] &, darts]; 
piapprox = Accumulate[insides]/Range[Length[darts]]
inner = Select[darts, Norm[#] <= 1 &];
outer = Select[darts, Norm[#] > 1 &];

Show[Plot[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis, AspectRatio -> 1,
PlotLabel -> n == Length[darts] TildeTilde[π, 4.0*piapprox[[-1]]]], 
ListPlot[{inner, outer}, 
PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[Tiny], Red}, {PointSize[Tiny], Blue}}, 
ImageSize -> {500, 500}]]
```

[image]

I tried to simplify this problem:

```
pts = RandomPoint[Rectangle[], 40000];

ListPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

**The problem is following:**

**How can I split set of points `pts` into two parts, "inside the circle " and "outside the circle"?**

Comment: You should also investigate RegionMember, e.g., `rf = RegionMember[Disk[]]; rf[darts]`

Answer (score 7):

*How can I split set of points pts into two parts, "inside the circle " and "outside the circle"?*

```
{in, out} = SortBy[GatherBy[pts, Norm[#] < 1 &], Norm[#[[1, 1]]] &];

ListPlot[{in, out}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What's the purpose of `SortBy`?

Comment: The approximation of $\pi$ can be recovered with `{in, out} = GatherBy[pts, Norm[#] < 1 &];
4*Length[in]/(Length[out] + Length[in]) // N`.

Comment: @anderstood, depending on the `Norm` of the first element in `lst`, the the first list in the output produced by `GatherBy` may be the "inside sublist" or the "outside sublist". Sorting the output of `GatherBy` makes the first list the "inside" one.

Comment: Comment to my own comment: it should be `{in, out} = SortBy[GatherBy[pts, Norm[#] < 1 &], Norm[#[[1, 1]]] &]`, cf kglr's comment above.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `Select`:

```
ptsin = Select[pts, Norm[#] < 1 &];

N[Length[ptsin]/Length[pts]]*4
(* 3.1496 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Playing with [`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) as shown in other answers:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {40000, 2}];

4` True/(True + False) /. CountsBy[pts, Norm[#] < 1 &]
```

> 3.1474

That doesn't help with drawing the graphic however.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the norm of the point and verify if it is inside the circle.

```
At = 4;
d = 2;
totalpoints = 40000;
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {totalpoints, 2}];
pointsinsidecircle = Select[pts, Norm[#] < 1 &];
counter = Length[pointsinsidecircle];
approxpi = (4. At counter/totalpoints)/d^2;
Print["approx \[Pi] = ", approxpi]
ListPlot[{pts, pointsinsidecircle}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

```
(*approx \[Pi] = 3.1328*)
```

Comment: You could you `Norm` directly, and avoid `AppendTo` which is very slow. Using `Select` is probably a much faster option.

Comment: @anderstood i have changed the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Tip: Don't save graphics as JPEGs, they become fuzzy and lose color fidelity. Use PNGs.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach:

```
inside = Pick[pts, Map[# ∈ Disk[] &, pts], True];
outside = Complement[pts, inside];
```

Also as pointed in a comment above:

```
inside = Pick[#, RegionMember[Disk[]][#], True] &@pts
outside = Complement[pts, inside];
```